# How do I check an array inside a IF statment

Tags: php, database, loops, if-statement

I have played a bit with php and started with database. My goal is to make a simple registration system and a login. The problem i have is that i wanna check so i don't make two accounts with the same name.

I tried to use a foreach statement in the IF statement, but that wasn't that popular.
My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM account";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $account = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if ($_POST["newAccountName"] != "" && $_POST["newAccountName"] != ( foreach ($account as $login) {$login["accountName"]}) ) { }
```

My question is, it is possible to check multiply statments without using && between one and an other? (like a loop as i tried)

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Take a look at [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Here's what I use `$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"; $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error()); if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo "Record exits."; }` to check if a record exists.

Comment: Wow, NO.  Use the `WHERE` clause in the SQL!  No loop necessary...

Comment: your approach isn't correct. Instead perform a query using the `where` clause and use the username like field to check that

Comment: To check multiple fields (more than one) use `$sql = "SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE email = '$email' OR username = '$username'";` you can replace `OR` with `AND` if you want to check for both, instead of one or the other.

Comment: @RobinAndersson Add `$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx","xxx", "xxx", "xxx");` on top and replacing `xxx` with your DB connection. And also replacing the DB fields with your own. This is taken from my own code that I presently use with 100% success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I use to check if a record exists.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx","xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email']);

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
die("Record exits.");
}

else
{
// Continue with insertion
}
```

To check multiple fields (more than one) use

```
$sql = "SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE email = '$email' OR username = '$username'";
```

You can replace `OR` with `AND` if you want to check for both, instead of one or the other.